# Devise - Is it possible to some users not need confirmation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

What I need if some user has an attribute, this will not need to be confirmed.
I've seen a couple of post about this but I cannot understand it (i'm kinda newbie in Rails).

In my user.rb

```
  def confirmation_required?
    if self.name == 'Joe'
      false
    end
  end
```

I tried that out but nothing happens, is like always is false. I saw another post with this code:

```
    def confirmation_required?
      !confirmed?
    end
#Put your conditions and job's done !
```

but how can I access to user data from my user.rb (model) Note that the user comes from HTTP Post request.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

EDIT

Also I could just re-write Devise::RegistrationsController to something like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def create
    super do
    if resource.name == 'Joe'
           resource.skip_confirmation!
           resource.save
    end
    end
  end
end
```

Do you think this could solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user model you can conditionally call `skip_confirmation!` in your `before_save` callback

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :skip_confirm  # arbitrary method name

  def skip_confirm
    if self.name == 'Joe'
      skip_confirmation!
    end
  end

end
```

or, you can use a block on `before_save`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save -> do
    if self.name == 'Joe'
      skip_confirmation!
    end
  end

end
```